# How to remove duplicate Cache-Control property from response headers

Tags: caching, iis, httpwebresponse

I need to remove duplicate entries of one property of response headers
"Cache-Control"

I actually want Cache-Control to come as private hence I went to IIS settings and went to the desired folder and added a customer http response header value as

"Cache-Control" with value as "private"

Now I am viewing as "no-cache,private" as its value when I see a request from my fiddler properties.

I need to do it from IIS level.

Any inputs?

[image: CacheControl property from Fiddler]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screen shot and my previous experiences, I could assume that u have set the Variable name in creating OutBound rule in IIS settings as RESPONSE_SERVER.
Please try creating the Variable Name as "RESPONSE_Cache-Control" without quotes and the value as "Private" without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

9 Years and 2 months later I had the same problem and a solution!

in the php.ini or in my case WHM/MultiPHP INI Editor look for:

```
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```

leave the field value empty:

```
session.cache_limiter =
```

Done, the second cache-control will dessapear, now go to your .htaccess and set your own cache-control headers:

## Cache control headers

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|gif|swf|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesmatch>
# css and js should use private for proxy caching https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching
<filesmatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
</filesmatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
```

Done, Enjoy!